# Can't declare variables after for loop in VS2012

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

Here is my code:

```
//main.c
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    int temp = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

The code could be compiled with my clang(602.0.49) but produces `error C2143` in VS 2012:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

Everything is good after modifying the suffix to `.cpp` or deleting `int temp = 0;`

Does this mean that I can't declare a variable after `for` loop in C project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 only supports the C89 dialect.

The C89 dialect forces you to put declarations before statements in the same block.

To fix the error, move the `temp` declaration right after the `i` declaration.

Comment: Or write C-style C++ - it supports much more recent C++ than C.